# How to create tomcat keystore from existing Godaddy .key and .crt file

Tags: ssl, tomcat, godaddy, keytool

I have existing SSL file for a domain which being used in Nginx and Apache.

How I can create tomcat `keystore` from existing GoDaddy .key and .crt file.

I tried below

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore k.key -file k.crt
```

> I got below error

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

> I got below how to create SSL from scratch, but I need reverse it,  https://in.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239
>
> Edit below is tomcat ssl config

```
<Connector port="${tomcat.ssl.port}"
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxPostSize="4194304"
maxThreads="150"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
executor="hybrisExecutor"
enableLookups="false"
acceptCount="${tomcat.acceptcount}"
connectionTimeout="20000"
disableUploadTimeout="true"
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
clientAuth="false"
sslProtocol = "TLS"
keystoreFile="/data/ssl/cert/keystore.jks"
keystorePass="123456"
keystoreType="JKS"
keyPass="123456"
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps. First export it to pkcs12:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey myprivate.key -certfile mycert.crt -name "mytomcat" -out mykeystore.p12`

Next, use the keytool command to create the jks file:

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mykeystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS`

Comment: Looks it will work, will give try on weekends,

Comment: I tried, now getting `SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9002"]
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect` i have used same password for source and destination.

Comment: now I can not start server with old config,

Comment: I think I have done something wrong with passwords, I will try with default keystore password.

Comment: http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/06/13/how-to-keystore-creating-jks-file-from-existing-private-key-and-certificate/